# AngularJS Programmatic binding

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that accepts a variable passed to it...

```
scope: {
      myindex: '='
    },
```

I then typically it use it like this, and all is good...

```
<my-dir myindex="index"></my-dir>
```

However if I were to generate my directive programmatically like this...

```
 var content = $compile(template)(scope);
 element.append(content);
```

How can I set the `myindex` variable?

Comment: does that `$index` referring to `ng-repeat` $index? please updated your question what exactly you want..

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are evaluated on the scope. `$index` in the view actually means `scope.$index`.

I don't really understand what you mean by "generating a directive programmatically", but if the template that you compile uses a variable `$index`, and you want this variable to have the value 42, then what you need is

```
scope.$index = 42;
```

Comment: Ok re-edited my example just imagine "index" is some variable in the controller, and it is being passed to the directive

Comment: Well, that doesn't change anything, except that you must now remove the $ sign in the variable.

Comment: I thought it was a pretty clear question, what is it you don't understand.